# What is the fastest way to deserialize JSON in java

Tags: java, json

I'm wondering what is the fastest way to parse json in JAVA ?

- Getting a default object graph using the library built in Array, and Object objects
- Getting a custom object graph using your own java bean

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mapping parsed JSON to Java bean involves additional steps, so using the raw interface (e.g. the streaming API of Jackson) will be faster. This way, you can also read until have what you need and stop parsing.

In response to @sikorski
From [Jackson Wiki](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDataBinding):

> Data binding is built using Streaming API as the underlying JSON
>   reading/writing system: as such it has high-performance [...], but has
>   some additional overhead compared to pure streaming/incremental
>   processing

This is pretty much inevitable. If you are writing a generic Jackson parser, you obviously can't use custom types in it. Therefore it follows that you'll have to construct the custom type after you read the JSON with the generic parser, and hence the generic parser will be faster. It's worth noting though that such overhead is very small and almost never something you need to optimize away.

Comment: So some libraries provide a way to parse JSON in a SAX way ?

Comment: @AdrienBrault: Yep. Like Jackson.

Comment: @Enno Shioji Please share some benchmark results/statistics or some other article for your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Well, The newest and wickedly Fastest one is Boon Json. I used it in my project and got an improvement of 20X. I actually got scared and double checked to see if Library is  functionally correct. Thankfully, it is :) :)
Boon has built in methods to serialize and de-serialize from/to Java Array/Maps and Custom Beans. 
More Here :   https://github.com/RichardHightower/boon

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) its a high performance library and its very easy to use :

```
  JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();

  System.out.println("=======decode=======");

  String s="[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";
  Object obj=parser.parse(s);
  JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj;
  System.out.println("======the 2nd element of array======");
  System.out.println(array.get(1));
  System.out.println();

  JSONObject obj2=(JSONObject)array.get(1);
  System.out.println("======field \"1\"==========");
  System.out.println(obj2.get("1"));    


  s="{}";
  obj=parser.parse(s);
  System.out.println(obj);

  s="[5,]";
  obj=parser.parse(s);
  System.out.println(obj);

  s="[5,,2]";
  obj=parser.parse(s);
  System.out.println(obj);
```

Comment: @AdrienBrault: i answered for the first part to parse the json , for me it means to decode it so maybe i misunderstood what you meant.