# DSL-Json in Java project is too slow

Tags: java, json, jackson, dsl

When implementing dsljson  in Java project, I see this is not correct. It is quite slow and hard to implement.

I create new object which implements from `JsonObject`

```
public static class abc implements JsonObject {

    public final int x;
    public final String s;

    public abc(int x, String s) {
        this.x = x;
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void serialize(JsonWriter writer, boolean minimal) {
        //parse the instance of object (abc) to json-string
    }

    public static final JsonReader.ReadJsonObject<abc> JSON_READER = 
                                     new JsonReader.ReadJsonObject<abc>() {
        public abc deserialize(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
            // Use jsonreader and common json converter (numberconverter, 
            // stringconverter) to parse json-string to an
            // instance of object (abc)
        }
    };
}
```

I create new : `DslJson<Object> dslJson = new DslJson<Object>();` to call "deserialize"/"serialize" when use it.

I think, my implementation is not correct hence it is too slow.
So if you have any experiences or example on for this `lib` then can you help me provide your ideas about that?

1. Do we have another way to use `dsljson`?
2. `DslJson` cannot use like `JackSon`?

   ```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   String jsonInString = "{\"age\":33,\"messages\":[\"msg 1\",\"msg 2\"],
                           \"name\":\"mkyong\"}";
   User user1 = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, User.class);
   ```

Comment: "dsljson is the best lib to parse", says who? (besides perhaps the author) And how did you measure it being too slow? Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230726/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-deserialize-json-in-java and/or Google for "fast json parser".

Comment: This is Performance testing (https://github.com/fabienrenaud/java-json-benchmark) of serialization and deserialization of Java JSON libraries. And in my project, I use about 30000 records to check the performance.

Comment: I recommend trying some libs yourself instead of picking one that someone else says is the fastest. They could be making a mistake, you could be doing something wrong that also shows up when using another lib. You could be measuring the parsing incorrectly, there's no way for someone else to tell.

Comment: I'm still hope someone can help me on it. At least I will have new experience about the dsl-json :). But thanks for your ideas :)

Comment: And my question just focus to someone else who have the experienced on this lib. Maybe they have some example which can share me...

Comment: I can resolve the issue... And the result is "dsljson is the best lib to parse json"

Comment: @BartKiers well, even the Jackson author says so: https://twitter.com/cowtowncoder/status/753068282442227712

Answer (score 2):

There are few examples in the library repository, eg: https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json/blob/master/examples/Maven/src/main/java/com/dslplatform/maven/Example.java#L82

Some things to try:

- reuse dslJson instance - it's costly to recreate it multiple times during testing
- avoid using Strings - byte[] or Streams are much more GC friendly data types

If DslJson is not the fastest, most likely there is something wrong with your setup :) (which means you should show more code - how exactly are you testing/benching library)

Comment: Yes. I knew this example but it look like not enough so I cannot run at local.
I will share full example on another thread.